# How to convert jQuery event handler into pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I used to have code that uses:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http"]', () => {});
```

To intercept link clicks. For complicated-to-explain reasons, I had to move this code somewhere *before* jQuery is loaded. How can I write this code in pure JavaScript?

Comment: I think there is no way to ask jQuery to bind an event handler before it is loaded into browser env. If there is a solution I would like to know

Comment: I don't specifically mean using jQuery; I'd like to cut jQuery out of it if at all possible, and do this using just JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the comments above, you can convert the event binding jQuery code above to something below using vanila JavaScript,

```
var links = document.querySelector('a[href^="http"]');
links.forEach(function(link) {
    button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
       // handling logic
    }, false);
} )
```

Code above bind event handler to every `a` element which can be expensive.

**Create an event delegate**

Add an event handler to the document and see if the target is the link you want,

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // check the target has an attribute of `a[href^="http"]`
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "a") {

    }
});
```

Code above using event bubbling to catch click event inside the document.

Comment: I prefer the second suggested solution as I believe it's more analogous to what I have, and also works for links added after the code runs. Thanks!